# Cycle through JSON with $.each

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I am using jquery $.ajax to submit data in my site.  I have form with the fields `email` and `name`.  I can submit the fields fine and get the return I want.  The following response is what I create when the email was black and the name field was blank.

```
{"success":0,"errors":{"email":["required"],"name":["required"]}}
```

The response is perfect, I think, but I can't loop through it.  Here is my jquery code to go through the response json.

```
<script>
$('#submit-button').click(function(){
var datalist="name="+$('#name').val()+"&email="+$('#email').val()+"&password="+$('#password').val()+"&user_level="+$('#user_level').val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: datalist,
url: '/admin/adminuser/save',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(rtn) 
{
  if (rtn.success==1)
  {
     alert('saved');
  } else {
     $(rtn.errors).each(function(i,e){
       alert(e);
     });
  }
}
});
});
</script>
```

I don't know ahead of time what will be in the errors array, but the `email` and the `name` match with the id of the html elements so I can (error) style them accordingly.  RIght now `e` alerts out as `[object Object]`, but I need email

Comment: Try using console.log when debugging, and not alert, that way you can actually see what you're getting, and not just guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you're trying to `alert` that won't show you much if you're dealing with objects as you are in this case.  Also you are using the wrong `each` function in jQuery.  Using `console`

This is the one you want:

```
$.each(rtn.errors, function (i, e) {
    console.log(i, e);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/DL24R/

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the other version of each, `$.each(rtn.errors, function(i,e){...});`